# Rendering Performance CloudOptimizedGeotiff Band calculation

Tags: leaflet, cloud-optimized-geotiff

Displaying [this](https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.swisseo_s2-sr_v100/2024-03-07t103911/ch.swisstopo.swisseo_s2-sr_v100_mosaic_2024-03-07t103911_bands-10m.tif) 4 band 16int COGTIFF file size approx 4GB in leaflet via

https://cms.geo.admin.ch/Topo/umweltbeobachtung/satromocogviewer.html?url=https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.swisseo_s2-sr_v100/2024-03-07t103911/ch.swisstopo.swisseo_s2-sr_v100_mosaic_2024-03-07t103911_bands-10m.tif

It is a valid COG according to gdal with 4 overviews, compressed etc

-> results in very slow performance on loading.

Firefox: After approx 10 succesfull accesses to the GOG tif file  I get an "unknown duration" Staus "waiting for response" as shown here
[image]

Edge: I get  Violation warnings in the console but tiles are loading after while

```
[Violation]'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 75ms
[Violation]'setTimeout' handler took 75ms
```

The data is loading quite fast, an I can observe the complete download finished
[image]

but afterwards it takes quite a while until it is rendered , I can't find any suspicous in
[image]

even if I use an RGB 8 bit File : RGB_COG_mosaic_2024-03-07t103911_bands-10m.tif it takes quite a while to render the image

https://cms.geo.admin.ch/Topo/umweltbeobachtung/satromocogviewer.html?url=https://cms.geo.admin.ch/test/topo/umweltbeobachtung/testcog/RGB_COG_mosaic_2024-03-07t103911_bands-10m.tif

I can't get the rendering/download accelerated : any ideas?

Here the complete code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>COG viewer SATROMO</title>
    !-- Version 3.1 --> <!-- full stretch -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <style>
        #map {
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.0/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster-layer-for-leaflet"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4leaflet/1.0.2/proj4leaflet.min.js"></script>
<! -- You might need this one as well
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-proj4leaflet"></script> 
--> 




<script>
    // Define custom CRS for EPSG 2056
   // Define custom CRS for EPSG 2056
    var crs2056 = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2056',
       "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs",
       {
         resolutions: [4000.0, 3750.0, 3500.0, 3250.0, 3000.0, 2750.0, 2500.0, 2250.0, 2000.0, 1750.0, 1500.0, 1250.0, 1000.0, 750.0, 650.0, 500.0, 250.0, 100.0, 50.0, 20.0, 10.0, 5.0, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05],
         origin: [2420000.0, 1350000.0]
     });

    var map = L.map('map', {
      crs: crs2056
    }).setView([46, 8], 1);

    var baseLayer = L.tileLayer('https://wmts.asit-asso.ch/wmts/1.0.0/asitvd.fond_pourortho/default/default/0/2056/{z}/{y}/{x}.png', {
        maxZoom: crs2056.options.resolutions.length,
        zIndex: 5
    }).addTo(map);

// Define a variable to keep track of the layer visibility
var layerVisible = true;

// Create a button to toggle the layer
var toggleButton = L.control({position: 'topleft'});
toggleButton.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'toggle-button');
    // Set the initial button text based on the layer visibility
    div.innerHTML = '<button onclick="toggleLayer()">' + (layerVisible ? 'Overlay OFF' : 'OFF') + '</button>';
    return div;
};
toggleButton.addTo(map);

// Function to toggle the layer
function toggleLayer() {
    if (layerVisible) {
        map.removeLayer(baseLayer);
    } else {
        baseLayer.addTo(map);
    }
    // Update the button text based on the layer visibility
    document.querySelector('.toggle-button button').innerText = layerVisible ? 'Overlay ON' : 'Overlay OFF';
    // Invert the layer visibility state
    layerVisible = !layerVisible;
}



    const url_to_geotiff_file = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("url");
    console.log("url_to_geotiff_file:", url_to_geotiff_file);

    if (!url_to_geotiff_file || !url_to_geotiff_file.endsWith(".tif")) {
        // If no URL is provided, or if it doesn't end with ".tif", display a message for non-supported imagery
        document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = "<h3>Non-supported imagery</h3>";
    } else if (url_to_geotiff_file.includes("ch.swisstopo.swisseo_vhi")) {
        console.log("This is VHI");
                
        // Parse the GeoTIFF data
        parseGeoraster(url_to_geotiff_file).then(function (georaster) {
            console.log("georaster:", georaster);
            // based on https://custom-scripts.sentinel-hub.com/custom-scripts/sentinel-2/l2a_optimized/    
        
        // Execute code for ch.swisstopo.swisseo_vhi
        // For example:https://cms.geo.admin.ch/test/topo/umweltbeobachtung/testcog/ch.swisstopo.swisseo_vhi_v100_mosaic_2023-10-16T235959_bands-10m.tif
        // yourVHICodeHere();
        // Define color map
    // Define the function to map pixel values to colors
    const pixelValuesToColorFn = value => {
        // Define your logic here to map pixel values to colors
        // For example, you can use a color scale or custom logic based on specific thresholds
    const scale = chroma.scale([
            '#C7BB95',
            '#FEFEE1',
            '#6E9F62',
            '#032816',
            'black'
          ]).domain([
            0,
            10,
            40,
            60,
            80
          ]);
        // Here's a simple example using a color scale:
        const color = scale(value).hex(); // Assuming 'scale' is defined elsewhere
        console.log("color:", color);
        return color;
    };

        // Modify the pixelValuesToColorFn function
        const layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
            attribution: "Contains modified Copernicus Sentinel data 2024, (c) Openstreetmap contributors provided by ASIT",
            debugLevel: 0,
            georaster,
            resolution: 256,
            opacity: 1,
            resampleMethod: "nearest",
            pixelValuesToColorFn 
        });

            layer.addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
         });
    
    } else if (url_to_geotiff_file.includes("ch.swisstopo.swisseo_s2-sr")) {
        console.log("This is S2 SR");
        
        
        
        // Parse the GeoTIFF data
        parseGeoraster(url_to_geotiff_file).then(function (georaster) {
            console.log("georaster:", georaster);
            // based on https://custom-scripts.sentinel-hub.com/custom-scripts/sentinel-2/l2a_optimized/    
        
        // Contrast enhance / highlight compress
        const maxR = 3.0; // max reflectance
        const midR = 0.13;
        const sat = 1.2;
        const gamma = 1.8;
        
        
        function evaluatePixel(val0,val1,val2) {
            //console.log("val0:", val0, "val1:", val1, "val2:", val2);
            const rgbLin = satEnh(sAdj(val0), sAdj(val1), sAdj(val2));
            //console.log("rgbLin:", rgbLin);
            //console.log("sRGB0:", sRGB(rgbLin[0]), "sRGB1:", sRGB(rgbLin[1]), "sRGB2:", sRGB(rgbLin[2]));
            return [sRGB(rgbLin[0]), sRGB(rgbLin[1]), sRGB(rgbLin[2])];
        }
        
        function sAdj(a) {
            return adjGamma(adj(a, midR, 1, maxR));
        }

        
        const gOff = 0.01;
        const gOffPow = Math.pow(gOff, gamma);
        const gOffRange = Math.pow(1 + gOff, gamma) - gOffPow;


        function adjGamma(b) {
            return (Math.pow((b + gOff), gamma) - gOffPow) / gOffRange;
        }
        
        // Saturation enhancement
        function satEnh(r, g, b) {
            const avgS = (r + g + b) / 3.0 * (1 - sat);
            return [clip(avgS + r * sat), clip(avgS + g * sat), clip(avgS + b * sat)];
        }

        function clip(s) {
            return s < 0 ? 0 : s > 1 ? 1 : s;
        }

        //contrast enhancement with highlight compression
        function adj(a, tx, ty, maxC) {
            var ar = clip(a / maxC, 0, 1);
            return ar * (ar * (tx / maxC + ty - 1) - ty) / (ar * (2 * tx / maxC - 1) - tx / maxC);
        }

        const sRGB = (c) => c <= 0.0031308 ? (12.92 * c) : (1.055 * Math.pow(c, 0.41666666666) - 0.055);


            const layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
                attribution: "Contains modified Copernicus Sentinel data 2024, (c) Openstreetmap contributors provided by ASIT",
                debugLevel: 0,
                georaster,
                resolution: 256,
                opacity:1,
                resampleMethod: "nearest",
                pixelValuesToColorFn: values => {
                    // Check if any of the bands have a value of 9999 or 0
                    if (values.some(value => value === 9999 )) {
                    //if (values.some(value => value === 9999 || value === 0)) {
                        // If any band has a value of 9999 or 0, return transparent color
                        return 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'; // Transparent color
                    } else {
                        // Apply min-max normalization to each band
                        const r = Math.round(evaluatePixel(values[0]/10000, values[1]/10000, values[2]/10000)[0] * 255);
                        const g = Math.round(evaluatePixel(values[0]/10000, values[1]/10000, values[2]/10000)[1] * 255);
                        const b = Math.round(evaluatePixel(values[0]/10000, values[1]/10000, values[2]/10000)[2] * 255);


                        // Return RGB color
                        return `rgba(${r},${g},${b},1)`;
                    }
                }
            });

            layer.addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
        });
    } else {
    console.log("This is RGB data");
     // Parse the GeoTIFF data
        parseGeoraster(url_to_geotiff_file).then(function (georaster) {
            console.log("georaster:", georaster);
            const layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
                attribution: "Contains user data, (c) Openstreetmap contributors provided by ASIT",
                debugLevel: 0,
                georaster,
                resolution: 256,
                opacity: 1,
                
            });
            layer.addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
        });
    };
    
    // Prompt user for GeoTIFF URL if none is provided
    if (!url_to_geotiff_file) {
        const defaultGeoTIFFURL = "https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.swisseo_s2-sr_v100/2024-02-23t103031/ch.swisstopo.swisseo_s2-sr_v100_mosaic_2024-02-23t103031_bands-10m.tif";
        const userGeoTIFFURL = prompt("Please enter the URL for the RGB GeoTIFF file (EPSG:2056):", defaultGeoTIFFURL);
        if (userGeoTIFFURL) {
            const parser = new URL(window.location);
            parser.searchParams.set("url", userGeoTIFFURL);
            window.location = parser.href;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = "<h3>No GeoTIFF URL provided</h3>";
        }
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Which part is slow: getting 4GB data or calculating RGB values?

Comment: Calculating the RGB values I assume . Since in cogeo viewer the raw file shows up pretty fast https://www.cogeo.org/map/#/url/https%3A%2F%2Fdata.geo.admin.ch%2Fch.swisstopo.swisseo_s2-sr_v100%2F2024-02-23t103031%2Fch.swisstopo.swisseo_s2-sr_v100_mosaic_2024-02-23t103031_bands-10m.tif/center/7.71,47.603/zoom/7

Comment: No need to assume. Put in some console logs and measure different phases.

Comment: did this now and updated the initial question. compared a 16int with a 8bit RGB file: both have a lag.

Comment: There is nothing you can do here to speed thing up. You can try with your question here: https://github.com/GeoTIFF/georaster-layer-for-leaflet/issues